# Nuxt 3 Fontawesome how to fix ERROR Failed to resolve import "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons" from "plugins\fontawesome.js". Does the file exist?

Tags: nuxt.js, font-awesome, nuxtjs3

I followed the docs from fontawesome to include them into my nuxt 3 project. https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue/use-with

I installed it with `npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest-3`

I also ran `npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons` and `npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`

then I created a plugins/fontawesome.js file (I quadruple checked the names here) and put the following code in it:

```
import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// This is important, we are going to let Nuxt worry about the CSS
config.autoAddCss = false

// You can add your icons directly in this plugin. See other examples for how you
// can add other styles or just individual icons.
library.add(fas)

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon, {})
})
```

I also added the neccesary code to the nuxt.config.ts so it looks like:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  app: {
    head: {
      title: "PAN-Biotech",
      meta: [
        {name: 'description', content: 'Your Cellculture stuff'}
      ],
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  css: [
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
  ]
})
```

Now the problem is when I start it with npm run dev I get the following ERROR:

```
 ERROR  Failed to resolve import "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons" from "plugins\fontawesome.js". Does the file exist?
```

What can I do here? I checked the name of the folder and file multible times and they do in Fact exist.

Comment: "@font…", not "@fort…"

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I copied most code from the docs directly, there stands fortawesome at all those points. I wondered that myself

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine chagning it to font in the nuxt.config.ts only creates more errors

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for not checking

Comment: Did you install the SVG packages, as instructed, before, installing FontAwesome?

`Install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core and any icon packages you plan to use.`

Comment: Yes I did I forgot to add that in my original question. I ran ```npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons``` and ```npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core``` (added it to the question)`

Comment: ah I forgot the @Anuga

Answer (score 0):

Install these other packages:

For npm:

```
npm install @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

For yarn:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```